# glossaries package - Default name of an entry to its entry label

Tags: glossaries

Is it possible to set the first argument of \newglossaryentry as the default value for the name key for all glossary entries?

For example, I would like to be able to write this:

```
\newglossaryentry{hi}
{
description={hello}}
}
```

and that this be understood:

```
\newglossaryentry{hi}
{
name=hi,
description={hello}}
}
```

Comment: `\newcommand\newglsentry[2]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1}, #2}}`?

Comment: Thanks @schtandard, that works! Only drawback is that it gives an issue with the key/value parsing if I enter the second parameter starting with a linebreak, i.e. I need to do that:
    `\newglsentry{revenue}{%
        description = ...`
instead of that:
    `\newglsentry{revenue}{
        description = ...`

Comment: I'll take your word for it. If you add an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/48973) to your question, I can debug further. Or, if this is fine for you as is, great.